# best away to return json of mongodb in django app

Tags: python, django, mongodb

How can I return a json of all documents in my collection?
I'm using pymongo, and I has one method that do this for me

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

db = client.sourceReggaeMusic

source = db.source


def findAll(self):
    return source.find()
```

but this method return something like this `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0618FDD0>`
and I need to do a for to print elements. Exists some away to get this result in json format? or convert this?

I need to convert to json, because when I make a request to some url, I'll response this json

Answer (score 0):

Use `list()` to convert your `cursor` iterable to a list of DB documents then serialize this list to a JSON array and send it to your client. Something like this:

```
# in views.py
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse


def some_view(request):
    resp = HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(findAll())))
    resp['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return resp
```